# How to useNavigate in a reusable function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function i want to implement multiple times which is why im trying to make it reusable. The problem is that `useNavigate` dosent seem to work inside it. And i dont really understand why

Here is the function

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom"

export async function UpdateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder) {
    await fetch(
        "url/trashcan/" + (itemID) + ".json",
        {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
        )
        await fetch(
            "url/" + (folder) + "/" + (itemID) + ".json",
            {   
                method: "DELETE",
                body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
        )
        useNavigate(0);
}
```

the console says its an Invalid hook call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can't do this as a hook can be only called from a component or other hook, but that `useNavigate` hook just returns some value so that you can pass it as a normal argument. So all in all to make it working, in the component top-level code:

`const navigate = useNaviagate()`

And use it like this:

```js
UpdateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder, navigate);
```

And ofc function body has to be changed as well

```js
export async function UpdateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder, navigate) {
    await fetch(
        "url/trashcan/" + (itemID) + ".json",
        {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
        )
        await fetch(
            "url/" + (folder) + "/" + (itemID) + ".json",
            {   
                method: "DELETE",
                body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
        )
       navigate(WHERE);
}
```

But that passing of an argument is a little stinky, as it's clearly mixing responsibilities, and reusable code like that shouldn't know anything about redirecting, so it should be handled one layer above in the component code, like that:

```js
try {
  await UpdateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder);
  // if we succeed
  navigate(WHERE)
} catch (e) {
  // handle errors
}
```

Comment: i see your point and i think my code got a little more efficent for it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables from the hook to your functions. This also includes state setters and similar hook stuff.

```
const MyComponent = () => {
//Get variable in component from the hook
const navigate = useNavigate()

//use effect is not important. You can do it on button click too
useEffect(() => {
//Pass navigate to your function
UpdateTrashcan("My message", "myId", "folderName", navigate)
}, [])


return (<p>My component</p>)
}
```

```
export async function UpdateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder, navigate) {
    await fetch(
        //...)
        navigate("Whatever goes here");
}
```

Comment: i tried this before and it didnt work for some reason but now it did

Answer (score 0):

this is how you use useNavigate:

```
export async function yourFunction(){
// write your code here
return true;
}
```

and then in the component do this:

```
export default function SomeComponent(){
let navigate = useNavigate()
const func = async()=>{
const result = await yourFunction();
if(result) navigate(0)
}
useEffect(()=>{
func()
},[])
return (<> <div></div> <>)
```

Comment: unfortunatly that dosent work, the hook must be called in a function and the same error i had before pops up if i put ```let navigate = useNavigate()  navigate(0)``` inside the function

Comment: maybe you can do it in another way. try to return a value from your function to your component and then inside the component do the naviagte

Comment: i edited the code for you, check it out

Answer (score 0):

As your reusable function has nothing to do with **React** stuffs, `useNavigate` **Hook** can **Not** be used there. [React Router's official docs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) suggests for these cases to use `redirect` instead of `useNavigate`.

As a result you can change the logic like this:

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom"

export async function updateTrashcan(messagedata, itemID, folder) {
    await fetch(
        "url/trashcan/" + (itemID) + ".json",
        {
            method: "PUT",
            body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }
        )
        await fetch(
            "url/" + (folder) + "/" + (itemID) + ".json",
            {   
                method: "DELETE",
                body: JSON.stringify(messagedata),
                headers:{
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }
        )
        redirect("where you want to go");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks like useNavigate have to be used according to react rules.

useNavigate is a React Hook, so it can/should only be called in specific ways.
If you check the documentation about react hooks [here](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), it might give you that error because you are probably calling the hook from a "normal" javaScript function.
And that does against React's hook usage.

The function might not be recognized by react, because of missing imports, as is stated in the previous answer.

Or it's just the case of using the hook in the right place, which is, inside a react function or in a custom hook of yours.